# How to display list of staff using JS Interop in Blazor Server?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-jsinterop

Good day everyone.

I am currently working on my project in Blazor Server. I have a stored procedure named "getUser" joing two table(User and UserContact) in my SSMS and I am using JQuery ajax and I want to display the list of users(stored procedure) when clicking the NavMenu.
But I encountered an error : status 500 after OnInitializedAsync.

Here's my code below.

//c# code

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
      await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("getCStaffInfo");
  }
```

//javascript  function

```
window.getCStaffInfo = function () {
    debugger;

    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/user',
        method: 'GET',
        succes: function (data) {
            debugger
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

//controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController: ControllerBase
{
    private readonly SampleUserDbContext _context;

    public UserController(SampleUserDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetCStaffInfo()
    {
        // Execute the stored procedure and return the results
        var user = await _context.User.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE getCstaffInfo").ToListAsync();

        return user;
    }
}
```

//Program.cs

```
 app.UseMapControllers();
```

Note: I also tried fetching using services but still same error occurred.

Comment: You can't do JsInterop operations before the component is rendered.  However, there's a more fundimental question here.  " Why are you not doing all this in C# - like Weather Forecasts in the template?"

Comment: Hello @MrCakaShaunCurtis, I did use JS Interop using OnAfterRenderAsync and the error says that "Could not find getCstaffInfo", status 500 did not appear in the console. I already display some data using pure c#, its just I want to explore on how to call stored procedure in JQuery ajax.

Comment: I don't see that there's any point in using Blazor and then reverting to Ajax calls to get your data!  I'll leave someone else to answer, I've long forgotten all the ajax stuff.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis, it's okay. I'm just trying to explore.

Comment: You could "explore" racing a car with square wheels, also.  But if your goal is to drive a car optimally, you shouldn't.  Anyway, you've given code in which you've called your JS from OnInitialized, which is wrong.  You call it from the after rendered event, as this is the earliest time that the page's javascript code is available.  Also-- where have you linked your actual .js file?  You either need to link it in _Host.cshtml, or to use JS Isolation and load it in your component code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal example(I don't know your `User` class,so just tried with WeatherForecast class in default template):

in RazorComponent:

```
@inject  IJSRuntime JS

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Temp. (C)</th>                
            <th>Summary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>




@code{
    
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("ShowWeatherForecast");
    }
}
```

Create a js file(myjs.js) under wwwroot folder and add the jquery codes:

```
window.ShowWeatherForecast = function () {   
    
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/weatherforecast',
        method: 'GET',        
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            var tbody = $("<tbody></tbody>")
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                var tr = $("<tr></tr>")
                var td1 = $("<td></td>") 
                
                td1.append(data[i].date)
                var td2 = $("<td></td>")
                td2.append(data[i].temperatureC)
                var td3 = $("<td></td>")
                td3.append(data[i].summary)
               
                tr.append(td1,td2,td3)
                tbody.append(tr)

            }
            $('table').append(tbody); 
        }
    });
}
```

add the required js file in _Host.cshtml:

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/MyJs.js"></script>
```

Api endpoint:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
         };
        public IActionResult GetForecastAsync()
        {
            var weatherforecasts=Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now).AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            }).ToArray();
            //notice you have to return object result with 200 statue code to hit success call-back in ajax
            return Ok(weatherforecasts);
        }
    }
```

Now the result:
[image]

Although it could work,I don't think it's a good solution,usually we call api endpoint with  httpclient ,you could follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server)

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I'll try it on my sample project.