# How can I inject JQuery in Blazor Server application in .NET 6?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-jsruntime

Newbie here,anyone who can give me an idea on how to inject jQuery in my Blazor server app? Thank you.

I already injected `IJSRuntime` in my sample project and I want to add jQuery on it. If you're asking me why I would do that, it's simply because I want to explore more to be able to apply it on my future project.

Thank you so much.

Comment: jQuery is just JavaScript.  Include it in the header template like you would include any other javascript.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Hello, yeah JQuery is a JavaScript code. So I only need to add the JQuery CDN along with Javascript right? Thank you for your response.

Comment: I've never used jQuery in Blazor, but so far as I remember, you can either link to the CDN or download it and host it from your server.  The main think is knowing where to link your .js files.  (In my project it's in the <head> section of _Host.cshtml)

Answer (score 3):

You could add jquery to your wwwroot as below ,follow the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
[image]

[image]

add this line in _Host.cshtml:

```
<script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here's a minimal example in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77257022/how-to-display-list-of-staff-using-js-interop-in-blazor-server/77263353#77263353)

Comment: thank you. As much as I want to upvote your answer I can't since I am a new member and I am not allowed yet to upvote an answer. Once again, thank you for your response.